# Profiling data for Meteor application

Tags: meteor

I need design a dashboard for my meteor app. I need obtain profiling data: collections, publishhing, client subscriptions, etc

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible, [Kadira](https://kadira.io/) has done just that. There is also [meteor-analytics package](https://github.com/Tarang/Meteor-Analytics), more info on that in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZT5qmSAZaeI).

Comment: Thanks. I use Kadira, but I need create my owned custom dashboard for a meteor aplication server